# How to auto say Yes when run a command in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, editor, elisp, emacs24

I had to run the command `revert-buffer` many times recently and really frustrated to say **yes** whenever emacs prompts this message `Revert buffer from file abc.txt? (yes or no)`.

Is there anyway to auto say **yes** in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's just for interactive usage, I'd define an alternative function:

```el
(defun my-revert-buffer-noconfirm ()
  "Call `revert-buffer' with the NOCONFIRM argument set."
  (interactive)
  (revert-buffer nil t))
```

Alternatively, as the `revert-buffer` docstring tells you, take a look at the `revert-without-query` variable, in case that's a nicer solution for you.

Comment: actually I prefer your function because in other situations, I may still need Emacs to prompt. Thank you!

Comment: Seems like it does not work if emacs daemon is working on the background

Answer (score 3):

On a related side note, many people have the following line in their `.emacs` that will make confirmations just a single keypress (just <kbd>y</kbd> or <kbd>n</kbd>):

```
(defalias 'yes-or-no-p 'y-or-n-p)
```

Comment: Many people do, but I don't recommend it. There is a reason that Emacs has two different functions for this. If you don't like a *particular use* of `yes-or-no-p`, then consider defining a replacement command for that *particular case* that does the same thing but that uses `y-or-n-p`. As opposed to a *blanket* substitution of `y-or-n-p` for `yes-or-no-p` everywhere.

Comment: @Drew what's the danger of the blanket substitution?

Comment: @Tshepang: Edit vs single-char input. Same reason someone who designed a command thought that it would be better to use `yes-or-no-p` rather than `y-or-n-p`.  Why did s?he do that? You might disagree wrt the interface of that command. Or you might disagree wrt *all* commands, and always prefer `y-or-n-p`.  But at least assume that the person who defined the command had some reason for not using `y-or-n-p`. Generally, the idea is that having to type `yes` or `no` (a) might make you stop and think more or (b) might prevent making a choice you didn't intend by accidentally hitting the wrong key.

Answer (score 2):

I use this, similar to [what @phils proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19194683), but with non-`nil` `IGNORE-AUTO` arg:

```
(defun revert-buffer-no-confirm ()
  "Revert buffer without confirmation."
  (interactive) (revert-buffer t t))
```

And I bind it to `<f5>`, since that's what that key does generally, in MS Windows.

In any case, I agree (strongly) with those who have advised to define a separate command for this.  I would not bother with `revert-without-query`, unless you are *very* sure wrt certain files (*always*) etc.  It's best to let `revert-buffer` continue to act normally, and provide (and perhaps bind) your own command for interactive use. *You* know best when to not be bothered by a confirmation prompt.

Comment: Yep, my case is to refresh a log file. So keep typing "Yes" is so tedious.

Answer (score 0):

Customizing `revert-without-query` might be an option.

Answer (score 0):

While it is, as pointed out by other answers, preferred to redefine the `revert-buffer` function or the key binding, it is possible to auto-reply "yes" to *any function* using `yes-or-no-p` or for that matter `y-or-n-p` by something like the following:

`(defalias 'yes-or-no-p '(lambda (a &rest b) t))`

This may be very destructive to your data, so use at your own discretion.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following to turn all ‘yes/no’ confirmations to ‘y/n’ confirmations,
and default to yes for certain prompts. i add prompts to default-yes-sometimes as needed. note i don’t have to list the entire prompt, just a regexp that matches it.

```
(setq original-y-or-n-p 'y-or-n-p)
(defalias 'original-y-or-n-p (symbol-function 'y-or-n-p))
(defun default-yes-sometimes (prompt)
  (if (or
       (string-match "has a running process" prompt)
       (string-match "does not exist; create" prompt)
       (string-match "modified; kill anyway" prompt)
       (string-match "Delete buffer using" prompt)
       (string-match "Kill buffer of" prompt)
       (string-match "Kill Dired buffer of" prompt)
       (string-match "delete buffer using" prompt))
      t
    (original-y-or-n-p prompt)))
(defalias 'yes-or-no-p 'default-yes-sometimes)
(defalias 'y-or-n-p 'default-yes-sometimes)
```